# The routes of Angular 6 do not work with the "Router" module, I think I have an error but I do not know what it is

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I have the routes set and I have 2 Outlets, the primary and second called "Sesion", however, I established several routes for the "Sesion" Outlet, it only lets me go to the first, that is, when I press the "Ingresar" button ( you will see it later) it takes me effectively to the established route, and I change the component but when I try to change the contents of the Outlet with another button in the current component, it does not work anymore ... or to go back to visualize the previous component neither to go to another.

**This is my routes ():**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AccionesComponent } from './acciones/acciones.component';
import { SesionComponent } from './sesion/sesion.component';
import { PostulacionComponent } from './postulacion/postulacion.component'
import { VotacionComponent } from './votacion/votacion.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: AccionesComponent 
  },
  {
    path: "votacion",
    component: VotacionComponent 
  },
  {
    path: "",
    component: SesionComponent,
    outlet: "sesion"
  },
  {
    path: "siguiente",
    component: PostulacionComponent,
    outlet: "sesion"
  },
  {
    path: "votacion",
    component: VotacionComponent,
    outlet: "sesion"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**My app.HTML (default component)**

```
<div class="clearfix col contenedor">  
  <div class="column acciones">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <div class="column sesion"> 
        <router-outlet name="sesion"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Sesion.component.html:** **(This button works "ingresar")**

```
<div class="content1">
    <div class="content2">

      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="tit"><b>Inicio de Sesión</b></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input class="inputs" type="text" name="nombre" value="Usuario o código de empleado">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input class="inputs" type="text" name="pass" value="Contraseña">
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="button" value="Ingresar" [routerLink]="[{ outlets: {sesion: ['siguiente'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <a class="tit2"><b>¿Olvidáste tu contraseña?</b></a>
      </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

**My acciones.component.html (content of primary outlet)**

```
<div class="tittle">#YoValoroOL</div>
<div class="text"><p>Apoya a tus colegas para que reciban el reconocimiento 
  que se merecen en el marco de los valores que nos definen como empresa.</p>
</div>
<div class= "tittle2">OLSoftware</div>
```

**My postulation.component.html ()** **(This button doesnt work "votar")**

```
<div class="content1">
    <div class="content2">
        <h1 class="tit"><b>Postulaciones</b></h1>
      <div class="label row">
         Buscar por nombre:
      </div>
          <select class="inputs" name="nombrea">
              <option value="volvo">Vanessa Velez Portera</option>
              <option value="saab">Vanesa Velez</option>
              <option value="fiat">Stiven Duran</option>
              <option value="audi">Camila de la Espriella</option>
          </select>
      <br><br><br><br>
      <div class="label row">
          Buscar por rol:
       </div>
          <select class="inputs" name="passa">
              <option value="volvo">Desarrollador Front-End</option>
              <option value="saab">Vanesa Velez</option>
              <option value="fiat">Stiven Duran</option>
              <option value="audi">Camila de la Espriella</option>
          </select>
      <div class="content3">
        <a [routerLink]="[{outlets:{sesion: ['votacion'] } }]"
         routerLinkActive="active">Votar</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="button" value="Seleccionar">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My votacion.component.html: is just a default component

```
<p>
  votacion works!
</p>
```

please Help me, i dont know the reason to not work

This is the error:

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'siguiente'**

https://github.com/marco7247/APPDinam.git this is the code if someone could help me please.

EVEN IF I CHANGE THE ORDER TO THE ROUTES JUST WORK FIRST TIME WITH THE FIRST CHANGE.

Comment: Please add a StackBlitz sample if possible.

Comment: https://github.com/marco7247/APPDinam.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... Angular presents errors if you don't use the primary outlet, i have created two new outlets and i wasn't using the primary one, so... thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

The error "...**Uncaught (in promise):**..." is happening because the primary route cannot handle the 'siguiente' route.

To fix the route error you could add a primary catch all route:

```
{
    path: '**',
    component: AnotherComponent
}
```

or a primary named route:

```
{
    path: 'siguiente',
    component: AnotherComponent
}
```

Secondary routes aren't accessed via their name the same way as the primary routes.
The link to get to a secondary route would look like this `http://localhost:4200/(sesion:siguiente)`.

accessing  `http://localhost:4200/siguiente`, you will be hitting the primary route, and the secondary route will be resolved as `''`, that is why you are getting the `SesionComponent` contents in the secondary route-outlet.

You might want to visit the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets) to learn more about it as well.

## Update

also, the link needs to be fixed, this is the correct code to navigate the secondary route:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sesion: ['votacion'] } }]"
   routerLinkActive="active">Votar</a>
```

Comment: How does the browser link looks at the moment for you? it should look like this `http://localhost:4200/(sesion:siguiente)`

Comment: that link works but the problem begin under this line:

My postulation.component.html () --->

<a [routerLink]="[{sesion: ['votacion'] } }]"
         routerLinkActive="active">Votar</a>

Comment: i edited the ask because i forgot to put the "sesion" component, the first component in the outlet "sesion", that button "ingresar" works and i got to access http://localhost:4200/(sesion:siguiente), in that moment the component is postulaciones.component... when i try to use the button "votar", it doesn't work and show me this

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'siguiente'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'siguiente'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError  .......

Comment: the router link should be `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sesion: ['votacion'] } }]"`

Comment: i edited again the code, that router link doesn´t work neither... i will search where upload my code and you could help me? if i send you my repository?